# Adding Stripe to Meteor -- Cannot read property 'setPublishableKey' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get stripe integrated into my meteor app using an Atmosphere package(https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe) and I can't figure out exactly why I'm getting this error. Here's what I have at the moment:

Repo cloned into packages/stripe

meteor list returns -- mrgalaxy:stripe 1.5.6 Stripe.js and Node-Stripe brought to Meteor.

When I tried to run 'meteor add stripe', I received 'stripe: no such package', so I added it the way it said on Atmosphere. (meteor add mrgalaxy:stripe).

It looks like the JS file for the package is loaded in the browser when I inspect it, but I'm still getting this error, which leads me to believe I'm not including the package correctly. Any thoughts? If any additional debugging information is needed, I'd be happy to provide it. Thanks in advance!

---

Main.js

```
'click #submit-btn': function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('PUBLISHABLE_KEY');      
  var Stripe = StripeAPI('SECRET_KEY');

  Stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 10,
      currency: "USD",
      card: {
          number: "4242424242424242",
          exp_month: "03",
          exp_year: "2014"
      }
  }, function (err, res) {
      console.log(err, res);
      return false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Stripe.setPublishableKey('YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'); can be in the client.

The click event should do a Meteor.call to a Meteor.method on the Server that runs the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is working for me now.  Didn't realize that the other code had to run server side and I didn't get that out of the debugging information either.